# Perl script that stores all top level directories and files in array

Tags: perl

I am making this too complicated I believe. I need a script that stores all top level directories and files (in the current working directory) into an array.

This is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = 'C:\tmp';
my @names = ();
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;

while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {

    next if ($file =~ m/^\./);
    $file = "$file"." ";
    # print "$file";
    @names = split( /\s+/,$file);
    foreach my $slot (@names) {
    $slot = "$slot"." ";
    }
    print @names;
}
closedir(DIR);
exit 0;
```

While this works, I know this is very sloppy and I am overly complicating it but I can't think of anything off the top of my head that would make this easier. I am trying to avoid using any perl modules other then the very basic (File::Find is ok, but any cnet modules aren't). So my question is, how can i simplify this? Thanks

Comment: just realized that was pointless to do. So no idea haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you want,

```
my @names = grep !/^[.]{1,2}$/, readdir(DIR);
```

your loop can be reduced to

```
while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {

    next if $file =~ /^\./;
    $file =~ s/\s+/ /g;
    $file .= " ";
    print $file;
}
```

if that makes any sense?

Comment: That first line was exactly what I needed! thank you! I need to get better at regex. Do you mind explaining what that does if you have the time?

Comment: File::Spec no_upwards method is a decent alternative for filtering out the current and upper working directory segments from a list of names.

Comment: @user3646369 it will read directory into @names filtering out `.` and `..` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the File::Slurp library like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Slurp;

my @files = read_dir('C:\tmp');
```

Comment: That seems like a really easy way to do it, unfortunately I am required to avoid any pm that aren't the very basic ones. That is a cnet module so I can't use it. Thanks though!

Comment: @user3646369: Don't you mean Skynet? :D

Comment: If you're not using cpan modules then whats the point of using Perl?

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding something, but I'm not quite sure what. There is only ever a single file name in `$file`, and there is no point in appending a space before you split on whitespace

Your array `@names` will contain the pieces of the file name separated by spaces, if it contains any spaces, otherwise it will be just the original file name

Then you put spaces at the end of every element of `@names`, presumably to replace those removed by `split`, so I wonder why you used `split` in the first place

Finally, `print @names` will print the reassembled file name with an additional space at the end. Note that if there were multiple spaces in your original file name they will be reduced to a single space now

The easiest way to print an array of strings separated by spaces is to *interpolate* it into a double-quoted string

This program does what you asked, but leaves the original file names intact. It uses `grep` to put into `@names` only those file names that don't begin with a dot `.`. It also uses a *lexical* directory handle which is modern best practice

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = 'C:\tmp';
opendir my $dh, $dir or die $!;
my @names = grep /^[^.]/, readdir $dh;
print "@names\n";
```

Comment: Perhaps your filter regexp needs to be more flexible, since its perfectly valid for file names to begin with . i.e. .htaccess, .bashrc etc (although the OP uses a similar regexp).

Comment: @Chris: Maybe, but I wrote it so that it produced output equivalent to the OP's code. I have no idea whether that's what he intended

Comment: I realized me adding those extra white spaces was me being dumb and forgetting how arrays are formed. When i was printing an array before hand, there were no spaces between the elements which made me stupidly think that was wrong. So I confused myself. But your answer solves my problem so thank you!

Comment: @user3646369: If you write `print @names` then the contents will be printed without any spaces. But if you use `"@names"` then a string is created from the elements of the array with spaces in between. Actually, they are separated by the current value of the built-in variable `$"`, which is initially set to a space but can be modified for different effects. For instance, `local $" = ', '` will put a comma and a space between the items, or `local $" = ','` can be useful for generating CSV data.